# Giving command with Here document as parameter to bash function

Tags: bash

I'm giving some commands as parameter to this function :

```
function check_command 
{
  if ! "$1" 
  then
    echo "Error when executing $1 - exiting"
    end
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

Command execution is checked in function.

I'm calling this function with an fdisk command :

```
check_command "sudo fdisk $system_disk_path <<EOT
o
p
n
p
1

+100M
t
c
n
p
2

w
EOT"
```

But I get an error :

```
EOT: No such file or directory
```

How can I give a command with Here doc?

Comment: Everything is in double quotes? Or are your trying to pass the whole thing as a command? If so, you cannot use file operators after param expansion since they are processed before, you would have to use eval.

Comment: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0):

In order to give whole command as a single parameter. In this case, as said @123

> you cannot use file operators after param expansion since they are processed before

So, using `eval` is the solution :

```
function check_command 
{
  if ! eval "$1" 
  then
    echo "Error when executing $1 - exiting"
    end
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be far simpler to just define a `die` function and call that *after* your arbitrary command than it will be to pass it to a function:

```
die () {
  echo "Error: $1 - exiting"
  exit 1
}

sudo fdisk "$system_disk_path" <<EOT || die "fdisk failed"
o
p
n
p
1

+100M
t
c
n
p
2

w
EOT
```